# Append in ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder won't recognise Calculated Value (GDB path) as a path when used as target dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, append, error-000229

I am updating a Model built & still functional in ArcMap.

The model starts by running a piece of python that checks if a GDB with a parameter-defined name exists already, or creates it. Either way, it spits out the full path. The Data Type is set to Workspace.

Here's the model:

[image]

Everything visible runs fine, but when it gets to Append it fails and gives me the error:

> ERROR 000229: Cannot open 1\Testing_2_2023Jul21

> Failed to execute (Append).

In the tooltip you'll see that the GDB path is passed as "1". I had figured ArcGIS Pro was smart enough to handle this, given this is how it did itself. Indeed, not an issue when used in the FC to FC tools right before that. Just seems to be Append that can't handle it.

So, is that the issue? If so, how do I pass the path (while still checking for the GDB & creating it if needed) and have the tool actually work?

I originally tried to redesign it with logical operators for the GDB creation, but that would only work if the GDB was not present and created. When it was present, I couldn't figure out a way to pass the path to other tools. I won't elaborate too much as this question isn't about that, but if that is the best approach I may need to open another question to help with that.

I just don't understand why this won't work - is this a "Collect Values" moment? Is this even the actual issue?

Comment: Have you tried passing a directory at the beginning and somehow try to use that path? Something like, open the path, then use a tool or a small python-script to parse the path or something similar to set the workspace?

Comment: What is the full path to FC54? The number 1 before the \  is that a FeatureDataset name? If so, that might be the problem you can't start geodatabase dataset names with a number.

Comment: @Hornbydd the 1 is how ModelBuilder is passing the path to my GDB, so it's <root/directory/folder/mygdb.gdb>, hence why it works for the FC to FC processes but won't work when passed to Append.